# How to correctly use Dsolve?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

how can I `Plot` these Equations?

1)

```
(x-y[x])y'[x]== x+y[x]
```

2)

```
Sol = DSolve[{1/r^2*D[r^2*ψ[r], r] + Subscript[ν, ct] ψ[r] == 0, ψ[r0] == ψ0/(r0^2 Ω)}, 
    ψ[r], r] /. r0 -> 0 /. Subscript[ν, ct] -> 1/λct;
```

Comment: Please write your first expression in Mathematica format.  Also, if you wish to plot an expression, you must define all constants.  Please include their values in your question.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: how did you figure out dsolve and not the even simpler Plot?  `Plot[ψ[r]/.First@sol /. ψ0->1/.Ω->1/.λct->1,{r,0,1}]`

Comment: the first one is a bit more challenging as the solution is given in implicit form. You can use ContourPlot to plot the result

Answer (score 4):

```
 sol=DSolve[(x-y[x])y'[x]== x+y[x],y[x],x]
```

> [image]

```
 ContourPlot [ Evaluate@(First@sol/.C[1]->0/.y[x]->y) ,{x,0,2}, {y,-1,5}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot [ Evaluate@Table[First@sol/.C[1]->i/.y[x]->y,{i,-2,2 }] ,{x,0,2}, {y,-1,5}]
```

[image]

incidentally, this throws a spurious unable to solve warning.. (yet shows the plot just fine anyway ).

[image]

Edit: here is how to do it cleanly..

```
sol = DSolve[(x - y[x]) y'[x] == x + y[x], y[x], x]
sol = (List @@ sol)[[1]] /.  y[x] -> y  /. C[1] -> i
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Table[sol, {i, -2, 2}]], {x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 5}]
```